# calling sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it not possible to call this method from within a viewcontroller that is a subclass of UITableViewController?

I am trying this:

```
 NSString *key = [[self sectionIndexTitlesForTableView] objectAtIndex: section];
```

But I get compiler warnings stating the viewcontroller may not respond to this method?

Comment: its delegate method of tableviewcontroller. so its called whenever you reload the table.

Comment: so this is not the correct way....                                                                                                                    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        
    NSString *key = [[self sectionIndexTitlesForTableView] objectAtIndex: section];
       
    return [[[self countryDicts] objectForKey: key] count];
    
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   
    return [self.countryDicts allKeys];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Apple Documentation, It seems to be the optional member of `UITableViewDataSource`
Then

**you can't invoke it on any object but only implement this in your class ...**

```
    // Asks the data source to return the titles for the sections for a table view.

    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

So Use below in the class which confirm `UITableViewDataSource` protocol,

```
    - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      {

      }
```

Have a look to apple Documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: